# Get object from generic T.Type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the actual object from a `T.Type` parameter. Here is my function.

```
func inject<T: Injectable>(_ injectableClass: T.Type) -> T {
    let injectable = injectableClass as! Injectable
    //More code that returns what is needed but this is the error spot
}
```

I am creating a dependency injection framework and want to use it as follows

```
var mColorManager: ColorManager {
    return mAppModule.inject(ColorManager.self)
}
```

This works until I want to do what I am trying to do inside the inject function.

This is the error I get

> Could not cast value of type 'Project.ColorManager.Type' (0x610000244158) to 'Project.Injectable'

`ColorManager` is an `Injectable`.

How do I cast or get the actual class object from `T.Type`?

Comment: You mean you want to return an object of type `T`? Btw your current code makes no sense without more context.

Comment: Yes I left out the unneeded parts but I can add that in. I am creating a dependency injection framework but the root of the issue is that from `T.Type` or `Object.self`, I want to get `Object` from only knowing `Object.self`.

Comment: So you basically want to initialize an object just by knowing its type?

Comment: Not really, all I care about is the `Injectable` protocol. I want to be able to cast the to the object (which derives from `Injectable`) from only knowing the type.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I added the error.

Comment: That's not how types work. You cannot cast a type to a protocol and since you already know that `injectableClass` conforms to the protocol it wouldn't make sense either. _"I want to get Object from only knowing Object.self"_ this quite literally means that you want to initialize an object by knowing its type, so you are contradicting yourself. Please try to explain what is it you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm unsure about how clearer I can get. It seems like you understand what I want to do. If you do, perhaps you can provide me with the correct way to do this or point me to a resource that can. Would you like to see more of the `inject` function? Perhaps that could help. The point of what I am trying to do is make it as easy for the developers to use my DI framework by calling it as such in the question (using ColorManager for example).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I guess what I am trying to do in the function is say 

"We know that T is of Injectable. But we want to know if this certain T of Injectable has these criteria that the protocol defines. For example Is this T of Injectable a singleton (Injectable.isSingleton())? If so, do this. If not, do that."

This is why I need to know how the T of Injectable inherits the functions and what it returns since this needs to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: If your goal is to decouple then it might be better to use protocols. That way there wouldn't be tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an `init()` to the protocol. I was then able to say

```
let realInjectableClass = injectableClass.init()
```